# Setting Cache-Control header for content with mime type text/html only

Tags: nginx, cache-control

I am working on a single page application built using Angular. My application renders on the client so all the requests that do not point at static assets should be handled by Angular router. This is done using the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    sendfile on;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

The `location` instructs nginx to try the files first then fall back to `index.html` if files does not exist. Now what I am trying to achieve is to set `Cache-Control` header to HTML files only.

I can do the following:

```
        if ($uri = /index.html) {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        }
```

But it will not work because the URI does not contain the HTML extension

I also tried this:

```
        if ($sent_http_content_type ~ "text/html") {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        }
```

But it has no effect. What I mean by has no effect is that I check the headers sent in the browser from the server and using `curl -I` but the headers are never sent.

I cannot test for URLs because they are dynamic and I cannot rely on extensions because the URLs doesn't have them. How can I set the header based on the Content Type?